# Iphone: app action slow first time then fast

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, performance

I have noticed that every single user interface action which is done for first time is slow. The very same action the next time is fast.

It deals with the sdk embedded functionality such as the camera, or my own functionalities such as my opengl button animations.

I have read that building for running could solve the problem, but for my case it doesn't.
Anyone has met a similar phenomena ? and how did you address it ?

Cheers,
Stéphane

Comment: It's most likely to do with the fact that the objects in question aren't cached. Once they are, it is quick to load the data!

Comment: i suspected that. do you know a way to force the caching ?

Comment: Try presenting the object and then immediately dismissing it. That may work. For a view, simply setting the view's `alpha` value to `1.0f` should cache the view.